# Which method to solve this differential equation? Laplace?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation?
$\frac {dP(t)} {dt}=Ae^{t/\tau}P(t)-BP(t)+C$
where $A,B,C, \tau$ are constant.
Should I use Laplace transform or some other method?

Comment: The solution can be found using the integrating factor method, though your answer won't be elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we shuffle things around a bit this is the same as:
$$P'-(Ae^{t/\tau}-B)P=C$$
so we can try first of all to solve for $C=0$:
$$P'(t)=(Ae^{t/\tau}-B)P(t)$$
$$\frac{P'}{P}=Ae^{t/\tau}-B$$
$$\ln P=A\tau e^{t/\tau}-Bt+Const.$$
then substituting this back into your original equation you can try to find the particular solution

Comment: Should be $$\log P=A\tau e^{t/\tau}-Bt+Const.$$

Comment: @Raffaele yes of course sorry did this too quick#